# How to slightly alter _layout for one specific page?

Tags: templating, include, layout

I have a _layout which includes a contact button:
`{% include '_contact-button' %}`

This creates a small contact button in the bottom right of every page that when clicked expands into a contact form. I would like this to be on every page of the site except the Contact page as it has it's own contact form. Is there a way in the contact template to not include _contact-button while still using _layout? Something like `{% dontInclude '_contact-button' %}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting it inside of a simple block as the default value...

```
{% block contactButton %}
    {% include '_contact-button' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Then on your one-off page, override that block with emptiness...

```
{% block contactButton '' %}
```

Untested, but that should do the trick!

Comment: Ah I didn't realise you could override a block. That worked great. Thanks Lindsey!